# Node bundling with electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm having a electron app which starts a node server upon start up. This application works well during development and testing as Node.js is installed in my computer.

My question is: How do I ensure that my electron app will run at client's computer even if there is no Node.js installed at client's computer? In that case how do I bundle a local version of Node along with my application and start that local node.

Can anyone suggest me anything to get started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Electron combines Chromium and Node.js into a single runtime so your app can run without Node.js installed. To ensure that, you can start a simple virtual machine, then install any Electron-based app, such as Atom, Slack, etc to see they work.

However, when you finished building your app, you will need to release it as a complete package by using electron-packager or similar tools. Trying to install your released package in several different environment by yourself is always required.

If you are new to Electron, it may be good to get started with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: Hard to find info. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Dong Nguyen, my app includes some background scripts in the extraResources/ folder.  I would like the app to be able to invoke those in production even if the user does not have Node.js installed.  Is there a node binary that is itself bundled with Electron?

Comment: the electronbuilder is the answer... @ZackBurt

Comment: Heh, @gumuruh, that was not sufficient for our needs.  We ended up doing a bunch of work with Webpack and CopyPlugin to get it to behave exactly as we wanted.

Comment: did you post the completed steps somewhereelse about it @ZackBurt?

Comment: Nope, the code belongs to my client, but both WebPack and CopyPlugin are well documented. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/